# RestSharp - deserialize json response with invalid key name (contains a period )

Tags: c#, json, serialization, restsharp

I've been stuck on this for awhile.  I have a JSON response sending me keys that include periods.  For example: "cost_center.code"

How can I get this into my object?  I'm not getting any errors but the value is just coming in as null and isn't being deserialized into my class.

Here's my classes:

```
public class Result
{
    public string company { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string employee_id { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    [DeserializeAs(Name="cost_center.code")]
    public string cost_center { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Result> result { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the JSON response:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "company": "My Company",
      "first_name": "First",
      "email": "example@fakeaddress.com",
      "employee_id": "123456789",
      "last_name": "Last",
      "cost_center.code": "12345"
    }
  ]
}
```

I execute with:

```
var response = client.Execute<List<RootObject>>(request);
// this returns null
Console.WriteLine(response.Data[0].result[0].cost_center);
// all other values return fine ex:
Console.WriteLine(response.Data[0].result[0].company);
```

I've tried both with and without the DeserializeAs.  I'm not sure its even working.  Am I using this property incorrectly?  Is it a container issue with the List?

---

Edited and accepted the answer below to use JsonProperty.  For others who may come along this was the solution.

Added JSON.net nuget.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Set the JsonProperty as described:

```
[JsonProperty("cost_center.code")]
```

Changed my execute to:

```
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Then deserialized it like this:

```
var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response.Content);
```

Afterwards I can access the value:

```
Console.WriteLine(jsonResponse.result[0].CostCenter
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RestSharp Serialize/Deserialize Naming Conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037387/restsharp-serialize-deserialize-naming-conversion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following with properties having period in their names :

```
[JsonProperty("cost_center.code")]
public string CostCenter{ get; set; }
```

It should work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to user RestSharp natively or couldn't get the **Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer** support to work (which I couldn't), they just added support for proper deserialization of properties with dots in their names as of **106.1.0**.

See my response here: [Accessing properties with a dot in their name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36376524/accessing-properties-with-a-dot-in-their-name/47402430#47402430)