# how to deserialize a Json string that contain dot (.) in key name .Net

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

```
{
     "odata.metadata": "sometext",
     "odata.nextLink": "sometext",
    "value": [{
            "odata.type": "SP.Data.RegionsListItem",
            "odata.id": "07404daa-61b5-4947-af9f-38f29822f775",
            "odata.etag": "\"3\"",
            "odata.editLink": "Web/Lists(guid'65dc896b-df87-4145-98d9-57c7ea619e66')/Items(3)",
            "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
            "Id": 3,
            "ServerRedirectedEmbedUri": null,
             }]
    
}
```

this is an example of my Json string i cant change its key names any sugestion? thanks in advance.

Comment: What library are you using for deserialization?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RestSharp - deserialize json response with invalid key name (contains a period )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33009218/restsharp-deserialize-json-response-with-invalid-key-name-contains-a-period) also check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36376524/accessing-properties-with-a-dot-in-their-name/47402430#47402430

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the library you are using for deserialization you can mark model fields with corresponding attributes - for example [`JsonPropertyNameAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=net-5.0) for `System.Text.Json` or [`JsonPropertyAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) for `Newtonsoft.Json`.

`Newtonsoft.Json`:

```
public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("odata.metadata")]
    public string OdataMetadata { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("odata.nextLink")]
    public string OdataNextLink { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public List<Value> Value { get; set; } // do the same for Value type
}

 var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

`System.Text.Json`:

```
public class Root
{
    [JsonPropertyName("odata.metadata")]
    public string OdataMetadata { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("odata.nextLink")]
    public string OdataNextLink { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("value")]
    public List<Value> Value { get; set; }
}


var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(json);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create a class for your data, you can use annotations for the class members. For instance when using Newtonsoft.Json it works this way:

```
class MyData {

[JsonProperty("odata.metadata")]
public string Metadata {get;set;}

[JsonProperty("odata.nextlink")]
public string NextLink {get;set;}

... 
}
```

With other libraries, the annotations may be named differently. Also make sure, you are importing the correct namespace and use the correct annotations for the library you are using.  Ie for instance the System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyName annotation won't have any effect, when deserializing with Newtonsoft.Json and vice versa.

Then you can deserialize

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(thejsonstring);
```

and access the property with its .NET name

```
 var metadata = data.Metadata;
```